# Add private nuget source to docker build with GitHub secrets

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nuget, github-actions

I am currently getting a 401 unauthorised when trying to add the NuGet packet source to my docker build.

I started by adding the NuGet source URL into the docker file with:

```
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/blah/index.json -UserName "AZ" -Password $NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The logs show that it getting the URL correct but 401 as it's not looking like it's using the var "NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN".

*The NuGet auth token NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN is a GitHub secret which I'm passing as a env and using when setting up dotnet*

In my GitHub Workflow I am then passing these value in by using "--build-arg"

```
--build-arg NUGET_URL=${{ env.NUGET_URL }} --build-arg NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }}
```

GitHub Workflow:

```
      - name: Build and Push Docker image
        id: build-image
        working-directory: ./src/Blah
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          docker build --build-arg NUGET_URL=${{ env.NUGET_URL }} --build-arg NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN=${{ secrets.NUGET_TOKEN }} -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f Blah.Blah/Dockerfile .
```

Dockerfile

```
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/blah/index.json -UserName "AZ" -Password $NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
RUN dotnet restore "Blah.Blah/Blah.Blah.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Blah.Blah"
RUN dotnet build "Blah.Blah.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Currently blocked and this has been the first time I've used private NuGet packages with Docker containers. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry) mentions using `--store-password-in-clear-text` argument for the `dotnet nuget add source` command. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:

I passed the values needed as environmental variables.

**GitHub Workflow**

```
      - name: Build and Push Docker image
        id: build-image
        working-directory: ./src/Blah
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
          NUGET_URL: ${{ env.NUGET_URL }}
          NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ env.NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          docker build --build-arg NUGET_URL=$NUGET_URL --build-arg NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN=$NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -f Blah.Blah/Dockerfile .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG NUGET_URL
ARG NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN
RUN echo "machine nuget.example.com login <username> password $NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc
RUN dotnet nuget add source -n github -u AZ -p $NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text $NUGET_URL
RUN dotnet restore "Blah.Blah/Blah.Blah.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Blah.Blah"
RUN dotnet build "Blah.Blah.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
`
```